# How to get a selection.range before mousedown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, jquery-events, rangy

**I don't understand** why I can't get the right range object. It's hard for me to explain the problem.

For example: I have five divs, each div contain a phrase. Logically if I trigger a `mousedown` event in one of these div I can get the event-target. Ok, this is elementary.

But, if I work with the range object on a `mousedown` event, the event-target is always that I have clicked but the `range.startContainer` is pointing at the previous div;

Check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khela/cqxd4/)**:

---

```
 1 LineLineLine
 2 LineLineLineLineLine
 3 LineLineLineLine
 4 LineLineLine
 5 LineLineLineLine
```

**Steps for reproducing the problem ( See console ):**

1. Hold down your mouse button on first line ( Console say "undefined" **[*]** )
2. Release your mouse button ( Range is securely pointing at first line now )
3. Hold down your mouse button on the fourth line ( Console say "firstline" )
4. The console show the previous clicked line

**[*]** *Is undefined because the document don't have a range
yet, but this is insignificant because I can create one at fly and inject him in document.*

I can deduce that the mousedown event is executed before the range.. Or not?

Comment: Just a question: is your goal to detect what line is selected?

Comment: Obviously not :D. i want to get the right range on mousedown

Comment: So, what are you trying to do here, just confirming that mousedown is triggered before the range can be properly detected?

Comment: No, i want only to get the right "line range" at mousedown

Comment: Apparently yes, the range is created *after* the mousedown. Can't you just use mouseup instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think you can get the right range on mousedown, the trigger is faster than the range detection. You can use mouseup ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cqxd4/3/)):

```
$("div.line").mouseup(setPos);
```

Or add a small delay ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cqxd4/2/)):

```
$("div.line").mousedown(function() {
    setTimeout(setPos, 4);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the setTimeout idea.. You think that this "way" can cause some problems? Like as multi-triggering or something like that?